# Order a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter

What's the best approach to order a list on a ListView (or similar widget)?

I'm using [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) to display events on the calendar so I need to order the different events on one day by date (this field is already created for each event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  final items = List.generate(10, (index) => index + 1);

  void order() {
    final ascending = items[0] > items[1];

    setState(() {
      if (ascending) {
        items.sort();
      } else {
        items.sort((a, b) => b - a);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == items.length) {
            return FlatButton(
              onPressed: order,
              child: Text("Order"),
            );
          }

          return Center(child: Text("Entry ${items[index]}"));
        });
  }
```

Comment: so basically this will render every time I load my widget

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: basically I'd click at least once on every single day having the calendar so I guess we need to run these filters all the time to reorder again the events. I guess there is no such method to order by field in `ListView` but I was just wondering if it was possible to avoid the extra work (maybe I just overthinking this because that's not too much work for the app)

Comment: I'm coming from JS so that's why I'm a bit worried about these extra loops that I want to avoid. Not sure if that's a problem tho

Comment: In fact, your list items are event objects, not only one int, so you can order by any field.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I replied that 
"I guess there is no such method to order by field"

Comment: yeah, I can order by any field but doing the filter before. I mean, that's fine as long as there is no other possible way on the list widget

Comment: It’s okay to rebuild parts of your UI from scratch instead of modifying it. Flutter is fast enough to do that, even on every frame if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Example below shows how to order a list of dates in ascending or descending:

```
final list = [
      DateTime.now(),
      DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
      DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)),
      DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3)),
    ];

    //Order By Descending
    list.sort((a, b) => a.isAfter(b) ? -1 : 1);

    //Order By Ascending
    list.sort((a, b) => a.isBefore(b) ? -1 : 1);

    for (var item in list) {
      print(item);
    }
```

sort can be used in any collection, use in your list of events comparing the date field